# Can't update a document in CosmosDB from node.js app

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb, pug

This is most likely a rookie mistake but any help would be appreciated....  I am trying to update a document in cosmosDB from my node app (using PUG).  But when I invoke the replace method...

```
async updateItem(item) {
  const itemId = item.ticketId;
  const {resource: replaced } = await this.tickets.item(itemId,itemId).replace(item);
  return replaced;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: TypeError: 
 C:\Users\donko\OneDrive\vscode\appstart\views\editticket.pug:30
   28|       .form-group
   29|         label.ticket-label(for='fk_ticket_status') Ticket Status : 
 >    30|         select(name="fk_ticket_status" value=ticket.fk_ticket_status required
```

So my question is why is the call to the CosmosDb replace method failing on the page?  I haven't gotten to the point where my code should be re-rendering the page?  the item object is called via my router as:

```
  async updateTicket(req, res) {
   await this.ticketModel.updateItem(req.body);
```

By comparison, my addItem function works just fine:

```
async addItem(item) {
  debug('Adding a ticket to the database')
  item.submitted_date = Date.now();
  item.fk_ticket_status = 1;
  item.assigned_to = '';
  item.parent = '';
  const { resource: doc } = await this.tickets.items.create(item)
  return doc
}
```

Comment: can you paste the whole error

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. According to [Partial document update in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update), to update a document using replace, the client needs to read it, update it locally and then send it over the wire as a whole document Replace API call.  When I tried this, it worked fine:

```
const oldDoc = await this.getItem(itemId);
const newDoc = oldDoc;
newDoc.updated_date = Date.now();
//... more updates here
const {resource: replaced } = await this.tickets.item(itemId, itemId).replace(newDoc);
```